# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows users

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't seem to access my normal Windows filesystem on the Ubuntu command line in Windows, any tips? Not even sure if this is supported yet.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the environment is sandboxed, meaning it can't see any files outside the Ubuntu-related files; but I could be wrong.

Comment: I read somewhere that it was sandboxed, but you could access your filesystem with the bash line

Comment: I honestly don't know much about it. I suppose you could see if a `/mnt/` folder exists and if anything exists under that.

Comment: Yes, Cygwin uses /cygdrive/C, so I would expect this Ubuntu on Windows to mount the C drive as /mnt/C or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The windows file systems are located in `/mnt/<Drive letter>` by default. Keep in mind that there are caveats with file permissions given they aren't supported on ntfs.

Comment: To be accurate, NTFS supports ACL based file permissions, which are richer than Linux' DACs. WSL exposes files/folders in the Windows filesystem with the user's effective permission set, but may revert to 777 in some cases where mapping between DAC & ACL looks to be permissive.

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the following:

```
cd /mnt/c/dev
```